# Majapahit territory in its peak

Tags: indonesia

Is there any proof that [Majapahit kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majapahit) territory  consist of all area of Nusantara Archipelago (now Indonesia). What I know that the sole proof of this claim was the only book authoring by Mpu Tantular. But there are no something like 'prasasti' or similar. In fact there are some kingdom like Ternate Sultanate Or Even Samudra Pasai that coexist with and precede Majapahit establishment.